# Текст в QLabel

Tags: qt, c++

У текста в QLabel задан белый цвет. Возможно ли еще обвести текст красным? У виджета можно задать

```
label_->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid  #ff0000 ;");
```

Возможно ли тоже самое у самого текста?

Comment: Действительно, как сказал @Frest надо использовать HTML-теги. Например так: lbl->setText("<font color=red>Hello!</font>");

Comment: @embarcadero

- Мне кажется, что "обвести" значит "обвести," а "изменить цвет" значит "изменить цвет," как бы банально это не звучало.

- Как я понимаю, автор хочет получить в `QLabel` аналог результата [`-webkit-text-stroke`](http://www.cardeo.ca/adding-an-outline-to-your-text-using-the-css3-text-stroke-property/) в специфичном для `WebKit` `CSS`.

Comment: - Лично мне не удалось найти схожее свойство в `Qt Style Sheets,` поэтому думаю, что можно либо перегрузить `paintEvent` и в нем отрисовать обводку самостоятельно, либо просто продублировать `QLabel` так, чтобы результат выглядел как контур.

- Первый вариант универсален, второй - *может сработать* для некоторых шрифтов в пределах маленьких значений толщины контура и при правильном позиционировании. То есть, грубо говоря, можно подобрать такие параметры, что желаемый эффект будет достигнут, но решение будет неинвариантно относительно системы, рендерера шрифтов и, собственно, самого шрифта.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего средствами stylesheet этого не сделать. Попробуйте переопределить paintEvent.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я знаю там можно писать текст с использованием HTML тегов. Может это как то поможет.